# OpenCv cannot open non-standard frame size, even though OpenCv encoded the video

Tags: c++, opencv, video, image-processing

```
cv::Mat im1;
cv::VideoCapture vidCapture;
vidCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 313);
vidCapture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 621);
vidCapture.open("Image1.avi");  
vidCapture.grab();
vidCapture.retrieve(im1);
cv::imwrite("test.bmp", im1);
```

I have captured and recorded 8-bit grayscale video from cameras using OpenCv. The video size is 313x621 due to some custom lenses in front of the cameras. Unfortunately this seems to break the cv::VideoCapture, even though OpenCv encoded the video fine. I can open and play the video with no issue using media player, VLC, etc.

When I grab a frame using OpenCV I get what looks like only one channel of a color image. I also tried:

```
vidCapture.retrieve(im1, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

This produces the same sort of image as above, where it looks like OpenCv is capturing one channel of a color video. I stored the image using:

```
CvVideoWriter* writer1 = cvCreateVideoWriter("Image1.avi",  -1, 60.0, cvGetSize(videoFrames->back()), 0);
```

which successfully created an 8-bit grayscale video.

What does work, is if I pad the video frames to 480x640. All of a sudden OpenCv successfully decodes the video. While this is an option, it's insanely frustrating since I will have to batch-convert all of my videos, open them, then re-crop to 313x621 for post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether setting of CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT are supported by the backend of VideoCapture or not. It can be done by:

```
double retCPFW = vidCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
double retCPFH = vidCapture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

If retCPFW or retCPFH is equal to 0.0 then the properties cannot be set manually.

---

You should also try reading video without setting the properties:

```
cv::Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture videoCapture("Image1.avi");
videoCapture >> frame;
```